# MySQL DatabaseError 2005 (HY000) - Unknown MySQL Server Host - Python mysql.connector

Tags: python, flask

I'm encountering a DatabaseError with the following message when trying to connect to a MySQL server using Python and the mysql.connector library

Here's the Python code snippet where the error occurs:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import mysql.connector
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# Define a route to handle the form submission
@app.route('/personal_details', methods=['POST'])
def submit_personal_details():
    data = request.get_json()
    
    full_name = data.get('full_name')
    email = data.get('email')
    contact_number = data.get('contact_number')

    db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "",
    port = 25060,
    user = "hannah",
    password = "",
    database = "Users"
    )

    cursor = db.cursor()

    # Corrected SQL query with placeholders
    query = "INSERT INTO Users (name, email, contact) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    values = (full_name, email, contact_number)

    cursor execute(query, values)

    db.commit()

    cursor.close()
    db.close()

    return jsonify({'message': 'Successfully registered!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The code is an attempt to connect to a remote MySQL server hosted on DigitalOcean. The error message suggests that the MySQL server host is unknown. I've checked the host and credentials, and they seem correct.

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully connect to the remote MySQL server. Thank you in advance for your help!

I attempted to connect to a remote MySQL server using the provided Python code snippet, which uses the mysql.connector library within a Flask application. I used Postman to check the flask oink but received the database error I expected that the code would establish a connection to the remote MySQL server and insert data into the "Users" table as described. However, I encountered the following error:

mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'B.6dpp-api-db-do-user-12472806-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com' (8)

This error indicated that the MySQL server host was unknown, despite verifying that the host and credentials were accurate.

Here is the Vue JS code for the form:

```
<template>
  <div :class="$style.personalDetails">
    <div :class="$style.personalDetailsChild" />
    <div :class="$style.personalDetailsItem" />
    <div :class="$style.personalDetailsInner" />
    <div :class="$style.elevation05Parent">
      <div :class="$style.elevation05" />
      <b :class="$style.personalDetails1">
        <p :class="$style.yourPrivacyIs">Personal Details</p>
      </b>

      <!-- Form for personal details -->
      <form @submit.prevent="submitPersonalDetails">
        <b :class="$style.fullName">Full Name</b>
        <v-text-field
          :class="$style.inputBgVtextfield"
          v-model="formData.full_name"
          label="Full Name"
          required
        />

        <b :class="$style.email">Email</b>
        <v-text-field
          :class="$style.inputBgVtextfield1"
          v-model="formData.email"
          label="Email"
          required
        />

        <b :class="$style.contact">Contact</b>
        <div :class="$style.frameParent">
          <v-select
            :class="$style.frameVselect"
            v-model="formData.country_code"
            :items="['+60', '+61', '+62']"
            label="Code"
            color="#ffd600"
            required
          />
          <v-text-field
            :class="$style.inputBgVtextfield2"
            v-model="formData.phone_number"
            label="Phone Number"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <v-btn
          :class="$style.primaryButtonVbtn"
          color="#ffd600"
          variant="flat"
          type="submit"
          width="217"
          @click="submitPersonalDetails"
        >
          NEXT
        </v-btn>
      </form>
      <!-- End of form -->

    </div>
    <div :class="$style.yourPrivacyIsContainer">
      <p :class="$style.yourPrivacyIs">Your privacy is important to us.</p>
      <p :class="$style.yourPrivacyIs">
        We only need your phone number or email to send your redemption code.
      </p>
    </div>
    <img :class="$style.infoIcon" alt="" src="/info@2x.png" />
    <v-btn
      :class="$style.iconArrowLeft"
      color="#fff"
      size="x-large"
      variant="plain"
      prepend-icon="mdi-arrow-left"
      width="19.6"
      @click="onIconArrowLeftClick"
    />
    <v-btn
      :class="$style.homeVbtn"
      color="#000"
      variant="plain"
      width="41"
      href="/customer-home-page"
      @click="onHomeClick"
    >
      Home
    </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "PERSONALDETAILS",
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        full_name: "",
        email: "",
        country_code: "+60",
        phone_number: "",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onIconArrowLeftClick() {
      this.$router.push("/");
    },
    onHomeClick() {
      this.$router.push("/");
    },
    submitPersonalDetails() {
      this.formData.contact_number = this.formData.country_code + this.formData.phone_number;

      // Send the form data to Flask API
      fetch('/personal_details', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.formData),
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should first ,check the mysql server, did it can be connected from your computer by user and password, such as mysql client. Just like you show,it may be a question ,about mysql config or  firewall config，not about python or flask.

Comment: Im a beginner to this and I'm using a remote database in PMA. How can I make sure its working

Comment: try to install a  MySQL Client，such  as mysql workbench.

Comment: I have that but this is a remote database

Comment: If the sql client,can not connect to the remote databse,the python code can not connect to it ,either.